# Task Scheduler runs the task but does not execute PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012, task-scheduler

Just as the question states.

I am trying to schedule a PowerShell script to run every hour using the Task Scheduler on Windows Server 2012R2. This is a remote server.

The Task Scheduler runs the task without any errors. In the task History, it shows `Action Started`, `Action Copleted`, and `Task Completed`.

Settings of the Task Scheduler that are selected are as follows:

General - Run whether user is logged on or not, Run with the highest privileges.
Actions -> Action Start a Program Actions -> Program/Script "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" (location of pwsh.exe)
Actions -> Add Arguments -Executionpolicy Bypass -File "R:\Public\IT\Vantage_Utilities\CNC_Scripts\File Transfer\Fastems\CNC_File_Transfer_Fastems.ps1" 
Location -> Name of the local machine

The script generates a log file and it clearly shows that the script was not executed at all.
It runs flawlessly when executed manually (Right click -> Run with PowerShell 7).

I have tried changing the local disk of the script but it makes no difference if it is on R:\ or C:\

I am beginning to think there is an issue with the script itself because there is another script that is executed using PS Core 7 from Task Scheduler which works. Therefore, I am going to post the script here. It is a simple batch file that moves all the contents of one folder from one server to another. I achieve this in two functions. `Function MoveFiles` moves all the contents of the parent folder(excluding the subfolder called "Mazak"). The second function,`Function MoveMazakFiles`  function moves the contents of "Mazak" only. ( I am completely aware I could have done this using fewer lines of code but that is not the point here)

Code:

```
$logPath = "\\MMS25163S1\Public\IT\Vantage_Utilities\CNC_Scripts\File Transfer\Fastems\Log.txt"
$trancriptPath = "\\MMS25163S1\Public\IT\Vantage_Utilities\CNC_Scripts\File Transfer\Fastems\LogTranscript.txt"
$getDate = Get-Date -Format "dddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm "
$counter = 0
$mazakCounter = 0
Start-Transcript -Path $trancriptPath -Append
Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value ("LOG CREATED $getDate") -PassThru
#Sources 
$srcMca = "\\MMS25163S1\Public\NcLib\FromNC\*"
$srcMcaNameChg ="\\MMS25163S1\Public\NcLib\FromNC"
$srcMazak= "\\MMS25163S1\Public\NcLib\FromNC\Mazak\*"
$srcMcaNameChgMazak = "\\MMS25163S1\Public\NcLib\FromNC\Mazak"
#Destination 
$destMca = "\\Sidney2\MfgLib\RevisedPrograms\MC-A"
#Time with milliseconds
$time = (Get-Date -Format hh-mm-fff-tt).ToString() 

Function MoveFiles{
    Param(
        [string]$src,
        [string]$dest,
        [string]$srcNameChange
    )
   Get-Item -Path $src -Exclude *Mazak* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object{
        $counter++
        $fileName = $_.BaseName
        $fileNameExt = $_.Name
        Write-host $fileName -ForegroundColor Green
        Rename-Item -Path "$srcMcaNameChg\$fileNameExt"  -NewName ($fileName+"_"+"(Time-$time)"+$_.Extension);
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value ("Name changed: Time stamp added to $fileName ") -PassThru
    }
    Move-Item -Path $src -Exclude *Mazak*  -Destination $dest -Force
   Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value ("$counter file(s) moved to $dest") -PassThru
} 
MoveFiles -src $srcMca -dest $destMca -srcNameChange $srcMcaNameChg

Function MoveMazakFiles{
    Param(
        [string]$srcMazak,
        [string]$dest,
        [string]$srcNameChange
    )
    Get-ChildItem $srcMazak -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object{
        $mazakCounter++
        $fileName = $_.BaseName
        $fileNameExt = $_.Name
        Write-host $fileName -ForegroundColor Green
        Rename-Item -Path "$srcMcaNameChgMazak\$fileNameExt"  -NewName ($fileName+"_"+"(Time-$time)"+$_.Extension);  
    }
    Move-Item -Path $srcMazak  -Destination $dest -Force
    Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value ("$mazakCounter file(s) from Mazak folder moved to $dest") -PassThru
}
MoveMazakFiles -srcMazak $srcMazak -dest $destMca -srcNameChange $srcMcaNameChg

Stop-Transcript
```

I have been searching for a solution for days now. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/629472/running-powershell-script-through-windows-task-scheduler

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=Task+Scheduler+powershell